# how to get rid of the fraud transction made through a interface developed with ubercart-paypal in drupal

Tags: drupal, paypal, ubercart

i had developed a site in drupal using ubercart and paypal as default gateway, everything is working fine only one problem - some people making the fraud transaction through my site, i got log messages from paypal like "Noting Matched Transaction Declined" even after getting error messages the credit card is processed. Is their any method/settings in paypal or in the ubercart module to halt the transaction after getting this kind of error messages.

Comment: i got my answer: their is a Risk Control settings in paypal account through witch you can apply the level of security about the payment acceptance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noting to do with the ubercart module. At the paypal, settings are available in `profile` under section `Security and risk setting` where we can set the different filters to `accept` and `deny` the payment based on specific conditions.